# Positioning a responsive hero button when hero image has text

Tags: css, positioning

I am used to creating a hero image as a background image and overlaying a hero button on top as a relative/in-line component.

Today, I was given a hero image that has text on it (see below). The hero button is supposed to go under the text that says "Check out the Open Enrollment Overview...". But, two things are happening:
1. when I position the button as I usually would, the button doesn't stay under that text when I shrink the length of my screen.
2. the button won't go on top of the hero image but instead, is laying below the bottom of the image and won't go on top.

[image: Hero banner]

```
<!-- Hero Image-->
  <div id="banner" class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="../img/headers/bannerHome_OpenEnrollment.png" class="img-responsive" alt="open enrollment" tabindex="0">
<!-- Hero Button -->
        <div class="hero-text">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary hero-text">Learn More <img src="../img/icons/btnArrow_white.png"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
#banner .col-xs-12 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    background-color: #49c8f4;
    position: relative;
}
.img-responsive {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

.hero-text button {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #003057;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Klinic Slab Medium";
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Since the image is responsive, you can't use a hardcoded pixel value to position the button...use percentage values instead.

Comment: @Paulie_D so, use something like top: 50%, left: 75%?

Comment: Indeed...or whatever values work best for you.

Answer (score -1):

It is not considered a best practice to have text baked into the image. Preferably you would build out the text sections in html. This would allow them to be positioned relative to each other.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not best practice. But it's what the designer and the project owner agreed on. So, I'm trying to accommodate it.

Comment: It's possible to position the button absolutely at the bottom, but you will have to add breakpoints whenever the button starts to overlap to adjust it's position.